# How to repair on macOS 13.5 environment variables for a CONDA installlation with valid intelpython package

Tags: python, macos, conda, intel, macos-ventura

I have a good installation regarding `Intel python3.9` with all modules loading perfectly.

However, I have a bad behavior with the `conda` part of Intel OneAPI : I can't even do a `$ conda list` or a `$ conda env list` , I get the following message :

```
$ conda env list
__conda_exe:2: no such file or directory: /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/bin/conda
```

So I have done the following export :

```
export CONDA_EXE=/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/condabin/conda
```

And I redo the previous command, I get :

```
$ conda list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/condabin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

I don't know what to do further to fix this Intel Conda installation.

If someone have already met this kind of issue of could see what's wrong ... I would like to avoid to remove all the Intel python distribution part.

**EDIT :** I forgot to mention that I have into my ~/.zshrc this part :

```
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/condabin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
```

Comment: Could this post be transfered to Ask Different stack exchaange forum ? Indeed, the issue occurs on MacOS 13.5 Ventura. Regards

Comment: Please raise a query in **oneAPI Registration, Download, Licensing and Installation** [here!](https://community.intel.com/t5/oneAPI-Registration-Download/bd-p/registration-download-licensing-instal)